# Ubuntu on an Eeepc 1005HA netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, eeepc

I've been given an old Eeepc 1005HA netbook running Windows XP and want to switch to a Linux OS and remove XP completely.

Is this easy/advisable?

What's the best way?

The netbook has no CD drive I read about installing from USB but then the Ubuntu site mentions using the Windows installer (not sure if this is only applicable if you want to add Ubuntu to XP).

Also confused about setting new drive sizes. Device is described as CPU Intel ATOM N280 / 1.66 GHz, RAM 1024 MB.

Comment: I had one of those, gave it to a family member. It still works with Ubuntu 12.04. Use the USB method to install. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: It's relatively easy, depending on you level of expertise, so to speak. It's probably also advisable, since you are here. As for the best way, there are a few, and it's hard to tell which one's the best for you. I think the default, or regular installation should do, even if it is only the second or third best. Last, but not least, welcome to Ubuntu, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If this old PC supports booting from USB, this is the best way to do it. I'd rather not use WUBI, for it is known to contain lots of bugs.

The Ubuntu Website describes [how to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). If you've finished creating it, see whether this old computer supports *USB Legacy Emulation* (have a look in BIOS Setup) or is able to boot from stick natively.

If you are able to boot this Live System, you should get a screen like this:
[image: BIOS mode]

or this:

[image: EFI mode]

Now select *Try Ubuntu* and wait until you get to the desktop. You can play a bit to see whether you like it or not and can click *Install* on the desktop to install Ubuntu. The installation offers you to replace XP, to install it alongside XP or to configure everything yourself. From your question I guess that you'd like to replace XP. So select it and let the installation Wizard do the rest.

With your PC configuration I'd recommend to get Lubuntu or Xubuntu, which use LXDE or XFCE as desktop environments. Those to environments are designed to be more resource-friendly. I doubt your PC would be able to handle Unity or Gnome, the environments used in default Ubuntu.

If you can't boot from USB, you nearly have to use WUBI (although it's not recommended), as long as you don't want to set up a DHCP/tFTP server and try PXE (network booting)...

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

With old netbooks [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is a great choice. The interface is less pretty then Ubuntu but also takes up less system resources. Lubuntu gave my old Samsung NC10 (similar specs) a new lease of life. You can make a [USB installer with he standard method](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) but use the [Lubuntu (32bit) iso](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/saucy/release/lubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso).

In terms of speed on these specs I very much recommend Lubuntu over Ubuntu from my experience.